# mysql select rows with limit but also include the users with same votes beyond limit

Tags: mysql, window-functions, ranking

The table name is user_votes and we get the top five users according to vote count with this query

```
select * from user_votes order by votes desc limit 5
```

it works fine but now let's say the 5th user and the 6th user have the same vote count. Then this query will select only TOP 5 but will neglect the 6th user. We want to include the 6th user too as he has the same number of votes as the 5th

As in the attached image, the bottom 2 users with user_id [1,5] has the same votes, there is one more user with the same votes but query won't show it

The goal is to include all the users who have vote count 2 even though limit is 5. So minimum row count returned is 5 in case all the users have different votes but maximum depends on the last row votes column value. In this case its 2

[image]

Mysql version is **Ver 8.0.25**

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us the version of MySql in use. It matters because [DENSE_RANK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank) is only available in v8+.

Comment: updated, its Ver 8.0.25, checking DENSE_RANK()

Comment: It's because limit set the limit of excract rows, so it works normally showing only 5 rows. If you want to show the 5 best votes you have to change your code. But let's say 20 users have the same votes, how many rows you want to show? If you tell us what is your goal we can try to help you to find the right code.

Comment: sure, so we want to show the top 5 users according to votes count but if let's say 20 users have the same votes then we want to show those 20 too. So minimum row count is 5 if all users have different vote count but if any user has same votes as 5th user we want to show those users too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for the [DENSE_RANK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank) windowing function. Here's a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d6800dabbb8c1818abc2e2acbd1c51a3).

```sql
WITH ranking AS (
  SELECT user_id, 
         votes, 
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY votes DESC) ranking
  FROM vote
)
SELECT * 
  FROM ranking 
 WHERE ranking <= 5
 ORDER BY ranking;
```

These windowing functions allow you to specify various things like ranking easily.